# Checkstyle-IDEA Plugin incompatible with DevEcoStudio

Tags: checkstyle, harmonyos, deveco-studio

I am trying to configure the Checkstyle-IDEA plugin With the latest version of DevEcoStudio but seems it is incompatible with the same.

Steps I have performed in DevEcoStudio -
**Main Menu -> File->Settings->Plugins->Search Checkstyle**, results in **Nothing found** as you can see in below picture

[image]

**Also, I have tried installing it from [Checkstyle-IDEA marketplace](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065-checkstyle-idea) but it fails while installation with the following error -**

[image]

**DevEco Studio Version:**

```
DevEco Studio 3.0 Beta1
Build Version: 3.0.0.601, built on October 19, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.9+11-b944.49 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
open-source software
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1484M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.mayevskiy.intellij.sonar
```

NOTE: Reported this issue with the Checkstyle Plugin team too.
They also recommend using a previous version. Here is the [answer](https://github.com/jshiell/checkstyle-idea/issues/548)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [CheckStyle-IDEA v5.56.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZiyL.png) from [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065-checkstyle-idea/versions)

and install it manually from [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ym5NI.png)

Comment: Thanks, it worked!